# mysqli Google Store Locator error on echoing $dom ->saveXML

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps, mysqli

I am following a tutorial on how to make use of the Google Maps as a store locator [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3), however, my webpage is outputting an XML error:

[image]

What does the error mean? how will I resolve it?

I declared GLOBALS in a .php file which has the following information. This file is automatically called in my `require()`

```
$GLOBALS['SRVR'] ='myServer';
$GLOBALS['USER'] ='myUID';
$GLOBALS['PASS'] ='myPASSWORD';
```

and then I placed the code as demonstrated in the tutorial in a function, and I call the function. I also converted `mysql` into `mysqli`.
I also created the table named `markers` just like in the tutorial.

```
require("indexhead.php");

function MaptheStore() //I plan to add an argument later to populate stores
{
    // Get parameters from URL
    $center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
    $center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
    $radius = $_GET["radius"];

    // Start XML file, create parent node
    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
    $node = $dom->createElement("markers");
    $parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

        // Set the active mySQL database

        $db_selected = mysqli_select_db($GLOBALS['con'], 'myDB');
        if (!$db_selected) {
          die (mysqli_error($db_selected));
        } 

    // Search the rows in the markers table
    $query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) 
    * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) 
    * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
    FROM myDB.markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
      mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['con'],$center_lat),
      mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['con'],$center_lng),
      mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['con'],$center_lat),
      mysqli_real_escape_string($GLOBALS['con'],$radius));

    $result = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'],$query);
    if (!$result) {
      die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error($result));
    }

    header("Content-type: text/xml");

    // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
    while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
      $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
      $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
      $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
      $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
    }

return $dom->saveXML();
}


echo MapTheStore();
```

Finally, I pasted this to simulate the $_GET[] (`?lat=37&lng=-122&radius=25`), to test the page like in the tutorial.

Is the error caused by me converting the code to mysqli? how will I resolve it? what exactly causes the error?

EDIT: here is my table structure for `markers`
[image]

and here are it's contents...
[image]

EDIT: the pagesource of the webpage has this output, basically only my headers:

[image]

Comment: What does the output look like?  Sounds like there are multiple rel="" attributes in the XML.

Comment: That red image is the output. To that one person who downvoted, why the downvote?

Comment: The red image is not the output, do a view source on that page and add that to your question (and the "rendering up to the first error would be helpful as well).

Comment: That is the source of the xml that displays that error?  It shouldn't be HTML.  You have a configuration problem on your webserver.

Comment: How should the webserver be configured? I am using apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be something you have done in the database.

http://viper-7.com/Nv5tDB

That link above is the rest of the XML created, and it seems all fine, so the database is the likely cause.

Comment: would you like me to place a `select` output of the table? I copy and pasted the one provided from the example in the tutorial..

Comment: is there a distance there too ? cause in my tests there should be. like shown here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b88d3/3/0

Comment: $GLOBALS['con'] is defined at indexhead.php, the one require() is referring to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82585/discussion-between-n099y-and-malky-kid).